# Proportionally filling a frame with an image in ConTeXt?

Tags: graphics, floats, context, scaling

I have been trying to a achieve in ConTeXt what's called "Auto-Fit" in Adobe InDesign, specifically the "Fill Frame Proportionally" kind of Auto-Fit. And from what I gather from the description in [ConTeXt Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/useexternalfigure) this should be possible. Unfortunately, however, I haven't been able to make it work, which is why I would like to ask for help.

Here's a MWE (btw, this resembles an older question discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335078/figures-floats-and-section-headings-on-new-pages-in-context)):

```
\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\setuplayout
[
  backspace=11.67mm,        width=131.25mm,
  topspace=21.21mm,         height=254.57mm,
  headerdistance=13pt,      header=13pt,
  footerdistance=13pt,      footer=13pt,
  rightmargindistance=13pt, rightmargin=39.5mm,
]

\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided, location=]

\definehead[PageSection][section]
\setuphead[PageSection][
  page=right,
  continue=no,
  style=\ssb\bf,
]

\starttext

\chapter{Testing Proportional Fitting}

\dorecurse{3}{\input{knuth}}

\placefigure[leftpage,none]{}
  {\externalfigure[http://www.hardwickagriculture.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/placeholder.jpg] [
      width=\textwidth,
      height=\textheight,
  ]}


\PageSection{Here's a Section on a New Page}

\dorecurse{3}{\input{knuth}}

\stoptext
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image: An image filling the type area in ConTeXt]

As you can see, the image is scaled to the size of the type area, which is *almost* what I want. I would like for the image to scale proportionally, though (and be cropped as necessary). So, I did some research and found the parameter `factor: max` [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/useexternalfigure), which seems to be perfectly suited ("aspect ratio is kept, the image is scaled to the bigger (oversized) variant"). However, the result of adding the parameter...

```
\placefigure[leftpage,none]{}
  {\externalfigure[http://www.hardwickagriculture.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/placeholder.jpg] [
      width=\textwidth,
      height=\textheight,
      factor=max,
  ]}
```

is this:

[image: An image fitted to the type area in ConTeXt]

Indeed, the image is scaling proportionally now, but it's not filling the frame anymore. So, I thought, I must have misunderstood the meaning of the `factor` and also tried `factor: fit`. Surprisingly, the result is exactly the same (i.e. no difference).

Can anybody offer any ideas as to how to achieve this? Am I on the right track trying the factor parameter? Is this a bug? Or are there other solutions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to do something I once wanted to do, but I'm not sure. You can look at [this old thread](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2014/077898.html). I hope it helps.

Comment: Oh, yes. Thanks for sharing that thread. I will have to try that, but after having read through all the solutions posted, I'm pretty sure that this is more or less exactly what I was hoping for. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it. By the way, actually, I assumed that `factor: max` was supposed to do exactly that and thought that I had found a bug. Now, judging from the last paragraph in the thread ("We should convince Hans to add this functionality (...) with factor=clip") I am wrong. Do you happen to know, is this is being worked on?

Comment: I am glad if it helps. I am on travel, and cannot write long answers at the moment, so I invite you to write an answer on your own with this solution, and to accept it. Good luck with the typesetting!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following mickep's suggestion (thank you very much!) I am going to post an answer to this question myself - just in case, anybody else is having the same problem.

So, originally, I thought that some setting for the `factor` parameter should achieve in ConTeXt what's called "Fill Frame Proportionally" in Adobe InDesign (i.e. scale the image proportionally until it completely fills the intended space, then clip it), but that doesn't seem to be the case. Indeed, there's even a suggestion for Hans to "add this functionality to the `scale` macro with `factor=clip`" [here](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2014/077907.html).

Anyway, to solve my problem at hand, I copied the code suggested on [this page](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2014/077903.html) and added it as a module (file `t-scaleandclip.tex`) in the right directory:

```
\unprotect

\newdimen\d_scaleandclip_actual_wd
\newdimen\d_scaleandclip_actual_ht

\newdimen\d_scaleandclip_requested_wd
\newdimen\d_scaleandclip_requested_ht

\newbox\scaleandclip_box

\installnamespace{scaleandclip}
\installcommandhandler \????scaleandclip {scaleandclip} \????scaleandclip

\setupscaleandclip
   [width=\textwidth,
    height=\textheight]

\unexpanded\def\scaleandclip{\dodoubleempty\doscaleandclip}

\def\doscaleandclip[#1][#2]%
   {\bgroup
    \ifsecondargument
       \edef\currentscaleandclip{#1}%
       \setupcurrentscaleandclip[#2]%
    \else\iffirstargument
       \doifassignmentelse{#1}
           {\let\currentscaleandclip\empty
            \setupcurrentscaleandclip[#1]}
           {\edef\currentscaleandclip{#1}}
     \else
       \let\currentscaleandclip\empty
     \fi\fi
     \dowithnextboxcs\scaleandclip_finish\hbox}

\def\scaleandclip_finish
     {%
       \d_scaleandclip_requested_wd \dimexpr\scaleandclipparameter\c!width\relax
       \d_scaleandclip_requested_ht \dimexpr\scaleandclipparameter\c!height\relax
       %
       \d_scaleandclip_actual_wd\wd\nextbox
       \d_scaleandclip_actual_ht\dimexpr\ht\nextbox + \dp\nextbox\relax
       %
       \ifdim\dimexpr\d_scaleandclip_actual_wd*100/\d_scaleandclip_requested_wd <
             \dimexpr\d_scaleandclip_actual_ht*100/\d_scaleandclip_requested_ht \relax
             \setbox\scaleandclip_box\hbox
                 {\scale[\c!width=\d_scaleandclip_requested_wd]{\box\nextbox}}%
             \scratchdimen=\the\dimexpr(\ht\scaleandclip_box - \d_scaleandclip_requested_ht)/2\relax
             \clip
               [
                 \c!voffset=\scratchdimen,
                 \c!height=\d_scaleandclip_requested_ht,
               ]{\box\scaleandclip_box}%
       \else
             \setbox\scaleandclip_box\hbox
                 {\scale[\c!height=\d_scaleandclip_requested_ht]{\box\nextbox}}%
             \scratchdimen=\the\dimexpr(\wd\scaleandclip_box - \d_scaleandclip_requested_wd)/2\relax
             \clip
               [
                 \c!hoffset=\scratchdimen,
                 \c!width=\d_scaleandclip_requested_wd,
               ]{\box\scaleandclip_box}%
       \fi
       \egroup}

\protect

The usage is:

\scaleandclip[width=..., height=...]{ ... any box ...}

simimlar to the usage of \scale macro.


\starttext

\dontleavehmode
\scaleandclip[width=3cm, height=3cm]{\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=3cm,frame=on]}
\scale[maxwidth=3cm, maxheight=3cm]{\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=3cm,frame=on]}

\dontleavehmode
\scaleandclip[width=3cm, height=3cm]{\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=3cm,height=10cm,frame=on]}
\scale[maxwidth=3cm, maxheight=3cm]{\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=3cm,height=10cm,frame=on]}

\dontleavehmode
\scaleandclip[width=3cm, height=3cm]{\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=10cm,height=3cm,frame=on]}
\scale[maxwidth=3cm, maxheight=3cm]{\externalfigure[cow.pdf][width=10cm,height=3cm,frame=on]}

\stoptext
```

Then, after loading the module with `\usemodule[scaleandclip]` I can use it like this:

```
\placefigure[leftpage,high,none]{}{
  \scaleandclip[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight]
    {\externalfigure[http://www.hardwickagriculture.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/placeholder.jpg] [
       width=\textwidth,
       height=\textheight,
     ]}
  }
```

Indeed, I find that when combined with the `\offset` macro this even gives me an easier solution than the `\bleed` macro to achieve full page (bleeding) figures as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335078/figures-floats-and-section-headings-on-new-pages-in-context).

Hope that helps. Thanks to anybody offering solutions!

Answer (score 6):

Use [`\clip`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/clip).  You might want to play with the `hoffset` parameter to get the right section of the image.

I also noticed that there is a spurious vertical space of `.5\baselineskip` above the picture.  I couldn't find out where it comes from but I [asked on the mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088751.html).  EDIT: Herbert got the answer, add `high` to the `location`.

```
\starttext

\input knuth


\startplacefigure
  [location={leftpage,high,none}]

  \useexternalfigure
    [placeholder]
    [http://www.hardwickagriculture.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/placeholder.jpg]

  \clip
    [width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]
    {%
      \externalfigure
        [placeholder]
        [height=\textheight]
    }

\stopplacefigure

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't known `\clip`, so that will definitely come in handy. However, I really would like to automatically fill the "frame", no matter which proportions the original image has (because the book will be published in different formats and I don't want to adjust each of the versions manually). So, I never know beforehand, if the image is in portrait or in landscape format.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer but a comment. The options to `\externalfigure` never clip the image, so you need to use `\clip` as in Henri Menke's answer.

I have always struggled to understand how the keywords given to factor work. Based on the code (`grph-trf.mkiv`), this is a high level explanation of what is going on (in pseudocode).

If `factor` is set to `max`, `fit`, `broad` or `auto` then the following calculations are done (I am ignoring `broad` because it is somewhat complicated).

1. First, `x_size` and `y_size` are calculated. That depends on the `scale` parameter, but we can approximate it as being equal to the natural width and natural height of the box. In case of images, if neither height or width are specified, `x_size` and `y_size` equal to the natural size of the image; if one is specified, say width, then `x_size` equals `width` and `y_size` is scaled proportionally; if both are specified, then `x_size` equals `width` and `y_size` equals `height`.
2. Then, `outer_v_size`, `h_size` and `v_size` are calculated:

   ```
   if maxheight is not set
      outer_v_size = textheight
      if inner or insidefloat or inpagebody
         outer_v_size = \vsize
         scrachdimen = \vsize
      else
        if \pagegoal < \maxdimen
           if \pagetotal < \pagegoal
              scratchdimen = \pagegoal - \pagetotal
           else
              scratchdimen = outer_v_size % \textheight
           end
        else
           scratchdimen = outer_v_size % \textheight
        end
     else % maxheight is set
        scratchdimen = maxheight
        outer_v_size = scratchdimen
     end
   end  

   if height is empty
     v_size = scratchdimen
   else
     v_size = height
   end

   if width is empty 
      h_size = \hsize
   else
      h_size = width 
   end
   ```
3. Then `used_x_size` and `used_y_size` are calculated.

   ```
   function calculate_norm(used, factor, maxdim, size, _size)
     switch(factor)
       case max: used = size
       case fit: used = _size
       case auto: used = maxdim
     end
   end

   if x_size > y_size
      caclulate_norm(used_x_size, factor, maxwidth, hsize, h_size)
      scale = used_x_size / x_size
      used_y_size = scale * y_size
   else 
      calculate_norm(used_y_size, factor, maxheight, outer_v_size, v_size)
      scale = used_y_size / y_size
      used_x_size = scale * x_size
   end
   ```
4. Finally, the box or image is scaled to `used_x_size` and `used_y_size`.

**Now, the key point to note is that the scaling depends on whether `x_size > y_size`.** So, you can get the desired behaviour by setting the `height` and 
`width` of the image.

Here is an example to play with:

```
   \setupexternalfigures[location={local,default}]
\useexternalfigure
  [placeholder]
  [http://www.hardwickagriculture.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/placeholder.jpg]

\defineexternalfigure[tall][width=2\textheight, height=\textheight]
\defineexternalfigure[wide][width=\textwidth,  height=2\textwidth]

\setuppapersize[S4][S4]

\showframe
\startbuffer
  \title{None - max}
  \page
  \externalfigure[placeholder][factor=max]
  \page
  \externalfigure[mill][factor=max]

  \title{Tall - max}
  \page
  \externalfigure[placeholder][tall][factor=max]
  \page
  \externalfigure[mill][tall][factor=max]

  \title{Wide - max}
  \page
  \externalfigure[placeholder][wide][factor=max]
  \page
  \externalfigure[mill][wide][factor=max]

  \title{None - fit}
  \page
  \externalfigure[placeholder][factor=fit]
  \page
  \externalfigure[mill][factor=fit]


  \title{Tall - fit}
  \page
  \externalfigure[placeholder][tall][factor=fit]
  \page
  \externalfigure[mill][tall][factor=fit]

  \title{Wide - fit}
  \page
  \externalfigure[placeholder][wide][factor=fit]
  \page
  \externalfigure[mill][wide][factor=fit]
  \page
\stopbuffer
\starttext

\getbuffer

\setuppapersize[A4][A4]
\getbuffer
\stoptext
```

Note that the image is never clipped. So, if you want to clip an image, then you will need to use `\clip` as in Henri Menke's answer.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate example. True, I struggled to understand what `format` is doing, as well, so thanks for the clarification. I will try the code as soon as possible (out of office right now), however the problem remains that I will still have to use two different definitions (i.e. the image will not automatically fill the "frame"). Actually, I thought that that's what the `format` parameter was supposed to achieve?